# Recursion to split a word according to certain linewidth (gd image)

Tags: php, recursion, gd

I am making an application that lets users write on an image using GD image. The imagebox is of a certain width. I'm facing a problem when users write words that are longer than the width of my imagebox. I wanted to use a recursion to split up the word, put I'm not that pro at it. Here's what I have.

```
function cutLongWord($word, $fullwidth, $font, $fontsize){

    $arrWords = array();

    splitWord($arrWords, $word, $fullwidth, 0, $font, $fontsize);
}

function splitWord(&$arrWords, $word, $fullwidth, $startIndex, $font, $fontsize){
$output = "";
$numStringLength = strlen($word);

for($i = 1; ($i + $startIndex) <= $numStringLength; $i++){
    $substring = substr($word, $startIndex, $i);
    //dimension of substring
    $dimensions = imagettfbbox($fontsize, 0, $font, $substring);
    //line width of substring
    $subLineWidth = $dimensions[4] - $dimensions[0];


    if($subLineWidth <= $fullwidth){
        $output = $substring;
    }
    else {

        $arrWords[] = splitWord($arrWords, $word, $fullwidth, ($i - 1), $font, $fontsize);

    }
}

return $output;
}
```

This one goes in an infinite loop. I'm kind of stuck. If you could point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: have a look at [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) or [chunk_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php). that would be lot easier.

Comment: also look at the comments [here](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php). these are full of functions like that.

Comment: I think your infinite loop is here:                      $arrWords[] = splitWord(&$arrWords, $word, $fullwidth, ($i - 1), $font, $fontsize);                                                   
if the word won't fit in the line, then you split the whole word again, but again the word wouldn't fit and so on

Comment: @redreggae problem with wordwrap and chunk_split is that I use variable fontsize, so I would have to do some other calculation to now how many chars would go on a line. Also, it differs if you would have say 'mmmm' or 'iiii' (m is wider than i). and I had been through those comments, but it wasn't exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to use recursion for this, as it overcomplicates things. You could probably do the same thing like this:

```
while(strlen($word) < width)
{
    // Split a section of text of width "width"
    // and add it to array.
}
```

Comment: I reprogrammed it with a while loop, and it works now. I just thought I should get the hang of recursion someday, as it seems like a powerful tool.

Comment: In that case, I think the problem might be in the fact that you have a for loop and recursion. Try something along these lines: `function splitword(...) { if($word >= $fullwidth) { $arrWords = splitword(...) } return $arrWords }` Recursion makes a lot more sense once you get your head around it.